# Невозможно использовать DCOM объект с учетной записью без прав администратора

Tags: .net, vb.net

У меня есть проблема с использованием DCOM в учетной записи без прав администратора. Есть приложение на VB .NET, сервис, стороннее приложение.
VB .NET взаимодействует с серисом прсредством .NET remoting, сервис использует DCOM для работы со стороннм приложением. Все корректно работает под админом, но в других случаях создание объекта происхожит корректно, но использование некоторых методов невозможно: сыпятся вот с таким вот исключением:

**Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))**

Я, конечно, поигрался с настройками в Component Services, попробовал то, что MS предлагает делать вот тут:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394603(v=vs.85).aspx

Но это, как вы понимаете, не помогло. Не могли бы вы помочь? Любые идеи будут полезными! Спасибо!

UPD Добавил StackTrace, может быть о чём-либо скажет

at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn) at RPCProRemoteObject.ControllerDocument.AttachController(String& vControllerName) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Comment: решение проблемы я запостил здесь:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556695/invokehelper-throws-access-is-denied-exception/31719530#31719530

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393266.aspx) и добавьте пользователя в группу "Distributed COM Users".

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло